# how to using plot() for list of data frame(3d convex hull)

Tags: r

I have a bunny example,I cut data for slices and become convex hulls

```
'bunnyConvexlhull'(data type:list).
```

I want to use `plot()` for `'bunnyConvexlhull'` (entire bunny by 3d convex hull).

```
library("onion")
library("geometry")
library("rgl")

data(bunny)
bunny <- as.data.frame(bunny)
maxZ <- max(bunny[,3]) #> 0.0587997
minZ <- min(bunny[,3]) #> -0.0618736
interval <- (maxZ-minZ)/0.01 #interval:0.01

#cut bunny data 
bunnySlices <- split(bunny, ggplot2::cut_interval(bunny[,3], interval))
#to convex hull
bunnyConvexlhull <- lapply(bunnySlices, function(x) convhulln(x, output.options = TRUE))
#plot
plot(bunnyConvexlhull$`[-0.0619,-0.0526]`, col="pink", alpha=0.7)# first slices
plot(bunnyConvexlhull$`(-0.0526,-0.0433]`, col="pink", alpha=0.7)# second slices
```

I just can plot a slice such as:

```
plot(bunnyConvexlhull$`[-0.0619,-0.0526]`, col="pink", alpha=0.7)# first slices
plot(bunnyConvexlhull$`(-0.0526,-0.0433]`, col="pink", alpha=0.7)# second slices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot the first slice like this:

```r
plot(bunnyConvexlhull[[1]], col = "pink", alpha = 0.7)
```

Then you can add all the other slices like this:

```r
lapply(bunnyConvexlhull[-1], plot, col = "pink", alpha = 0.7, add = TRUE)
```

Giving you the following 3D image in an rgl window:

[image]

Comment: I used to try lapply but get error, very thanks for you!